# Sudoku solver if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, sudoku

I am currently working on a little project: a automated Sudoku solver.
I created an option for the user to manually type in a number in one of squares according to the rules of Sudoku. This works perfectly and has been tested many times to make sure of this.

For the last step of this project I made an if statement which looks for the following:
If the user has left one or more squares open, the if statement will find them. Then it will create a random number between 1 and 9 and checks if this number has been used either in the same horizontal row, vertical row or in the same square, according to the rules of Sudoku. I have tried many different forms of this if statement, but none of them seem to work. Perhaps any of you could help me out. The if statement looks like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('File1').innerHTML.length == 0){

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    if (randomNumber !== square2  && randomNumber !== square3
     && randomNumber !== square10 && randomNumber !== square11 && randomNumber !== square12
     && randomNumber !== square19 && randomNumber !== square20 && randomNumber !== square21
     && randomNumber !== square4  && randomNumber !== square5  && randomNumber !== square6
     && randomNumber !== square7  && randomNumber !== square8  && randomNumber !== square9
     && randomNumber !== square28 && randomNumber !== square37 && randomNumber !== square46
     && randomNumber !== square55 && randomNumber !== square64 && randomNumber !== square73){

        document.getElementById('File1').innerHTML = randomNumber;
    }
}
```

File1 represents the first square of the Sudoku board. The other variables such as square5, square8 etc. are basicly the correspoding squares of the Sudoku board, where square8 represents the 8 square on the board counted from left to right.

Is there anyone who could explain why this if statement does not write the random generated number into the first square of the board?
********* UPDATE *********
So I got far enough to make it work, sort of. The programme places a random generated number in the correct square, BUT it is a completely random number from 1-9. It does not look at the conditions in the if statement. The programme still writes the number 3 for example even if this number is already in the horizontal or vertical line or in the same box. The if statement now looks like this:

```
function solve(){
if (document.getElementById('File1').innerHTML === ""){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if (randomNumber != square2 && randomNumber != square3   && randomNumber != square10 && randomNumber != square11 && randomNumber != square12 && randomNumber != square19 && randomNumber != square20 && randomNumber != square21 && randomNumber != square4 && randomNumber != square5 && randomNumber != square6 && randomNumber != square7 && randomNumber != square8 && randomNumber != square9 && randomNumber != square28 && randomNumber != square37 && randomNumber != square46 && randomNumber != square55 && randomNumber != square64 && randomNumber != square73){
        document.getElementById('File1').innerHTML = randomNumber;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Lars and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for new users that you may find useful. Regarding Sudoku, why would the `if` statement in the post find a number to enter in the first square if the if the random number has already been used in the first row, column or box? I suggest using an array for numbers on the board rather than variables named `square1` through `square81`. Such an array should allow iteratating through different solution programmatically instead of hard coding each possibility.

Comment: How are you assigning values to `square2`, `square3`... and so on? Your conditional check is using strict (non) identity (value and type) `!==`. If you are assigning the value as `innerText` or `innerHTML`, the `true/false` values will be the opposite of what you expect as the types will always be different (integer versus string). Try it with `!=` where "1" and 1 are compared by value and their type is ignored.

Comment: @DavePritlove Hi! I have assigned the variables square2, 3 etc. like this: 

var square1 = document.getElementById('File1').innerHTML;

the id corresponds to the first file in the table in the HTML file. I have changed the conditional check to !=, but unfortunately it is still not placing the random generated number in the first square.

Comment: @traktor The main idea is that users can enter random numbers according to the rules of Sudoku. When they are finished they can press a solve button and then the if statement will look for the squares without any value, so the ones they have left open and then generates a random number from 1-9. Once it has done that, it checks if the chosen number is either a duplicate in the horizontal row, vertical row or in the main box where is it placed in. I will try and mess around with my current code for a while and then I will definately look into that array example. I will have to do some research

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)` will return a digit 0-8, not 1-9. I'm a little confused why you keep mentioning a "random" number in Sudoku, when the rules of a puzzle only allow one specific correct digit per cell. So instead of "inserting a random number and then determining if it's correct", why don't you "look at the current row/column/square and determine the possible correct number(s)" instead? And then if a cell only has one possible correct number, that's the solution for that cell. Repeat until the puzzle is solved.

Comment: You may want to research Sudoku solving further: brute force methods to solve a puzzle by trying random numbers in unfilled squares need a backtracking method to get around early choices that prevent any solution ever being reached, typically using some kind of recursive programming technique.